# Does Scala allow overloaded constructor to have statements other than 'this'?

Tags: scala

I have a case class in Scala whose primary constructor takes "friends" as comma delimited string.  The secondary(overloaded) constructor takes "friends" as Array[String] and calls the primary constructor.  For some reason, "friends" in the primary constructor has to be a String and in the overloaded constructor, it has to be Array[String] .

In the secondary constructor, I think I need to check if friends is null before calling mkString, I tried to use "if" statment to check but it doesn't seem to compile and recoganize friends as an Array, so it doesn't allow me to call isEmpty, so does scala have similar thing to "? :" operator so that I can check friends within the calling of primary constructor?

```
 case class Person(val friends: String)
 {
      def this(friends: Array[String]) = 
      {
          if ( !friends.isEmpty)  
            // doesn't compile, error message: 'this' expected but 'if' found
              this(friends.mkString(",") // throw NULL pointer exception
              // can I do "this((friends.isEmpty)?"":friends.mkString(","))" here ?
       }
 }
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Error message is:  'this' expected but 'if' found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if-else` conditional expression in Scala yields a value, unlike other traditional languages, such as Java. You still have to make sure that `this` is the first expression in your secondary constructor. It would look like this:

```
def this(friends: Array[String]) = 
    this(if (friends != null && !friends.isEmpty) friends.mkString(",") else "")
```

A different approach could be to either accept and `Option[Array[String]]` or wrap it yourself with one:

```
def this(friends: Option[Array[String]]) = 
    this(friends.getOrElse(Array.empty[String]).mkString(","))
```

Answer (score 3):

`if` statement should work: `this(if(friends == null) "" else friends.mkString(","))`

A more idiomatic way in scala would be to use `Option`:

`this(Option(friends).getOrElse(Array.empty[String]).mkString(","))`

As for "having statements other than `this`", you can have them, but `this` must be the first thing you do in constructor. It is the same way in java as well.